# Connecting Java to Oracle Database using JDBC in Terminal

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, odbc

I'm trying to connect java to a Oracle database within terminal. I'm not very good at terminal and have been struggling with this for 3+ hours. Can someone explain to me how I can properly set my PATH so that java can see the necessary jar files, as well as how to configure my path so that I don't have to type in the path where java is installed everytime I want to compile and run. I undersatnd this is a question that can be googled, but I've been runninginto problem after problem. Please keep in mind that I'm doing this all through PuTTY as I am not on the machine itself. If someone could take the time to answer this question, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It would be most helpful if we knew the OS you were using; different OSes have different environment variables that may be required.

Comment: I'm on a windows machine but using PuTTY to ssh into a Linux machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't find jar files using the PATH. It finds them using the classpath you pass to the java command (or using the CLASSPATH environment variable, but I wouldn't recommend using it outside of a local terminal session):

```
java -cp /path/to/jar1.jar:/path/to/jar2.jar com.foo.bar.Main
```

To have the JDK in your path, you need to add `<JDK_PATH>/bin` (or `<JDK_PATH>\bin` on Windows) to the PATH environment variable.

Read the [following section of the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).